# How to regex with negative search?

Tags: regex, negative-lookbehind

I want to search a document for the following string

```
<whoName>[substring]</whoName>
```

where substring != "self"

so

```
<whoName>other</whoName>
```

would pass.

but

```
<whoName>self</whoName>
```

would fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this negative lookahead based regex:

```
<(whoName)>(?!self\s*<).*?<\/\1>
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kW4jL0/2)

**Regex breakup:**

```
<(whoName)>  # Match <whoName> and capture it ($1)
(?!self\s*<) # Negative lookahead that means current position is not followed by literal 
             # self followed by 0 or more spaces and <
.*?          # Match 0 or more characters (non-greedy)
<\/\1>       # Match closing tag using back-reference to captured group #1
```

Comment: This regex not match <whoName>selfie</whoName> or any substring that starts with self

Comment: Yes, I was updating and writing more details. Please check updated answer now.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
^<whoName>((?!self<).)*</whoName>
```

Tested in notepad++ and regex101

Answer (score 1):

You can find the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/406230/regular-expression-to-match-line-that-doesnt-contain-a-word).

You could use something like

```
<whoName>(?!self)[a-z0-9]*<\/whoName>
```

(try this out here: https://regex101.com/r/vW8sP3/1).

As you can imagine the relevant part is `(?!self)`.